# Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE Android phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

`Phonegap` app is not installing on real device `LG500`.

Error is:`Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE`

Any suggestion ?

Comment: How about: remove some apps or other junk on the device so there is enough free memory available to install your app?

Answer (score 4):

```
You need to do two things after which this error will be resolved.

1. In your AndroidManifest.xml file add android:installLocation="preferExternal" within your manifest tag.

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.packagename.appname"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" 
android:installLocation="preferExternal">

2. More importantly, clear the cache data in your device. Goto settings -> storage -> click on cached data. This will clear the cache and free the space.

3. Reconnect your device, clean your project and again run it on the device. The project will now run on your device.
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the application from the device which you are planning to install if its already installed and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

This is so dumb, but in my case the problem was the following:
There was enough free disk space to store the app, but there was no free 'space' on my home screen to fit the icon - all places in the Grid are full. 
I solved this by adding a new 'page' to the home screen, so that there is space to fit the app icon.

Took me a few hours to solve - Using an Samsung Galaxy S2 with Android 4.1.2

Answer (score 0):

In your Android Manifest, just add `<manifest ... android:installLocation="preferExternal"...>` in the `<manifest>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Removal of the Cordova android package from the temp directory helped:

- `adb shell rm /data/local/tmp/android-debug.apk`

Alternatively you can see which other packages are in the dir and try to remove a release build for example:

- `adb shell ls /data/local/tmp/`
- `adb shell rm /data/local/tmp/android-release-unsigned.apk`